# Google sheets scripts editor and correctly parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to parse a JSON file from [Binance API](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#get-ohlc-data) so i can create a [candlestick chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart) on [google spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets).

Nevertheless i cannot seem to figure out how can this be achieved...
This is what i've tried so far:

```
function myJSON(){
  url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XXBTZEUR&since=0&interval=1"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
  coinsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var rawdata = JSON.parse(json);
  var data = JSON.stringify(rawdata.result.XXBTZEUR)
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
       var mdata = new Array();var obj = {};
       var utcSeconds = data[i][0];
       var mdate = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
       mdate.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
       open = parseFloat(data[i][1])
       high = parseFloat(data[i][2])
       low = parseFloat(data[i][3])
       close = parseFloat(data[i][4])
       obj['date'] = mdate
       obj['open'] = open
       obj['high'] = high
       obj['low'] = low
       obj['close'] = close
       mdata.push(obj);
       Logger.log(mdata);
       coinsheet.appendRow(mdata);
    }
  }
}
```

While running the function [Logger gives this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86S22.png) but yields the following error:

> This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 2000000 cells

How is that possible ? There are only 720 records, and why doesn't the mdata variable get overwritten at each loop? Shouldn't this create a table with column names and data automatically ? Totally lost here. Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: if you log `coinsheet.getLastRow()`, what do you get?

Comment: Hi @LioraHaydont thanks for bumping on this. It yields "0.0"

Comment: try with `coinsheet.appendRow(mdata[j]);`

Comment: Nope. Same error. And `mdata[j]` didn't work. Tried with `data[j]`

Comment: currently, what is the content of coinsheet? could it be a graph or something?

Comment: Your for loop with variable `j` is executing your code 8 times for every item in your results. As you don't use variable `j` anywhere other than in your loop, it seems that you can remove this loop. This will most likely fix the cells limit issue.

Comment: @LioraHaydont - You were right the first time. Only that `getLastRow()` doesn't return all available row. I had to use `getMaxRows()` to get all rows which were in fact more than the amount limit, and then add to delete them all (except 1) with `deleteRows()`. Something like this `var start = 1; var end = coinsheet.getMaxRows() -1; if (end != "0.0"){coinsheet.deleteRows(start, end)}`.

Regardless, my code had a series of bad practices/misconceptions that I'm now more aware because of [chuckx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373815/chuckx) answer. Thank you all. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated implementation (tested on a sheet, and it successfully appends rows):

```
function appendApiData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var coinsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var url = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XXBTZEUR&since=0&interval=1';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var data = parsedResponse.result['XXBTZEUR'];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var utcSeconds = data[i][0];
    var mdate = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
    mdate.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
    var open = parseFloat(data[i][1])
    var high = parseFloat(data[i][2])
    var low = parseFloat(data[i][3])
    var close = parseFloat(data[i][4])
    var row = [mdate, open, high, low, close];
    Logger.log(row)
    coinsheet.appendRow(row);
  }
}
```

And here's an excerpt from the logs:

```
[18-06-01 11:44:41:028 PDT] [Thu May 31 23:45:00 GMT-07:00 2018, 6452.5, 6452.5, 6447.6, 6448.2]
[18-06-01 11:44:41:146 PDT] [Thu May 31 23:46:00 GMT-07:00 2018, 6450.5, 6450.9, 6450.5, 6450.6]
[18-06-01 11:44:41:263 PDT] [Thu May 31 23:47:00 GMT-07:00 2018, 6450.6, 6450.6, 6447.1, 6449.7]
[18-06-01 11:44:41:364 PDT] [Thu May 31 23:48:00 GMT-07:00 2018, 6449.5, 6449.7, 6447.2, 6447.2]
[18-06-01 11:44:41:446 PDT] [Thu May 31 23:49:00 GMT-07:00 2018, 6447.2, 6450.5, 6447.2, 6450.5]
```

Some notes regarding what I changed:

- if you're not going to use the intermediate values, you can string together method calls (i.e. `JSON.parse(response.getContentText())`)
- avoid `JSON.stringify()` followed by `JSON.parse()`, you're needlessly encoding/decoding data
- **remove the inner loop**, you're referencing the array items explicitly by index, so there's no  need for it. As it stands, the inner loop is causing you to process each row *[number of row items]* times
- avoid `new Array()`, just use an array literal (i.e. `[]`)
- when constructing the row, you need to create an array of row values, not an array containing a single object. See the [Sheet.appendRow() example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. @LioraHaydont were right the first time. Only that `getLastRow()` doesn't return all available row. I had to use `getMaxRows()` to get all rows which were in fact more than the amount limit, and then add to delete them all (except 1) with `deleteRows()`. Something like this `var start = 1; var end = coinsheet.getMaxRows() -1; if (end != "0.0"){coinsheet.deleteRows(start, end)}`.

Regardless, my code had a series of bad practices/misconceptions that I'm now more aware because of [chuckx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373815/chuckx) answer. Thank you all. Cheers

Comment: [chuckx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373815/chuckx) tried to upvote but I dont have necessary reputation to change this. Thank you once more.

Comment: You can [mark this answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). That would be much appreciated.